# how to get to 'username' from 'username@server' on ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, user-accounts, sudo, su

My terminal on ubuntu 20.04 looks like:

[image]

I don't know what is `@server` after the username, but I guess it is a leftover from an earlier now meaningless installation of something.

My question is how to get rid of it?

How can I make my terminal just start with `pr`? (I want this because I suspect this is the reason [why I can't install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387141/why-cant-install-with-curl-on-ubuntu) certain things on my computer).

I can do sudo but su gives back authentication failure:

[image]

I want to have a *normal* terminal without the `@server`. Whatever program causes `@server` can be uninstalled or it can even stay as long as it does not interfere with my installation:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387141/why-cant-install-with-curl-on-ubuntu

I am no way a Linux expert, therefore any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what is @server after the username

It looks like the computer's *hostname* – your Ubuntu installation was given the name `server`. It can be changed using `hostnamectl set-hostname`, or through the `/etc/hostname` file, or through Ubuntu's Settings app (in the "About" section, I think).

> I want to have a normal terminal without the `@server`

That *is* a completely normal terminal.

(Or a normal *shell,* more specifically – it's the shell that outputs all text. The terminal just shows it, like a web browser only shows web pages but doesn't really decide their contents; the distinction becomes important if you're searching where to customize it.)

What you have in the screenshot is exactly the default prompt style used by the Bash shell at least on Debian systems – I'm less sure about Ubuntu, but I do think Ubuntu also uses the same style by default as Debian does.

So if your terminal previously did not show the `@hostname` part, it's very likely that you *had* customized it before. It's also possible that it *did* show the hostname, but the actual hostname was different – e.g. maybe it used to be `pr@desktop` or `pr@prs-computer` originally. If that is the case, just change the system hostname back to whatever it was before (see 1st part of the answer).

> How can I make my terminal just start with `pr`?

If you want to hide the whole `@hostname` part, search for "bash prompt customization" – the style is defined in the `PS1=` variable, which is usually stored in `~/.bashrc` to be loaded every time a new terminal is opened.

Again, note that the shell prompt's appearance is purely visual: whether it shows something or not, it doesn't change anything about how the shell (or the rest of the system) actually works.

(Changing the actual hostname, i.e. renaming the computer, *can* have an effect, such as temporarily breaking 'sudo' until reboot – but it can't break 'su'; if your 'su' is broken, that's a different thing entirely.)

> I want this because I suspect this is the reason [why I can't install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387141/why-cant-install-with-curl-on-ubuntu) certain things on my computer

No, it really isn't.

At the very least, you're confusing a symptom for the cause.

Comment: Thank for the answer. It does not solve my problem but at least it points me to the right direction by ruling out what does NOT cause the 'curl' installation to fail. Should you have any hint regarding the underlying (linked) question, please let me know.